# Telerik RadGridView Columns AutoSizeMode

Tags: c#, telerik, radgridview

I am creating columns for a Telerik RadGridView as follows:

```
RadGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("ColumnName"));
RadGridView.Columns[ColumnName].AutoSizeMode = BestFitColumnMode.AllCells;
```

While I am setting the `AutoSizeMode` for the column. However it is doing nothing. I have tried to put the second line in different methods and just cannot get it to work. I've placed it before and after my code to load data and still nothing.

Has anyone used the `AutoSizeMode` for the `RadGridView` successfully and if so can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: RadGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].AutoSizeMode=BestFitColumnMode.AllCells;

Comment: derloopkat, what you pasted is what I'm using that does not work.